# Running a java service on a server with dynamic ip

Tags: java, redirect, service, dns, port

I am trying to setup a java service (a server) which accepts tcp/udp connections from GPS tracking device on a user defined port (say 5555).

As i am not having an static ip on my server i can't configure my gps device to point to a specific ip address.

how about using a dynamic dns service like [no-ip.com](http://no-ip.com) so that i can have a static name mapped with my dynamic ip.

i can configure gps device to point to a domain like gpst.no-ip.org

will it redirect the gps device to port 5555 of my server if i use dynamic dns service.

Is their any other way of doing this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The dns-lookup will happen with no knowledge of the port. So it is up to your application to decide which port to use.

I think binding the dynamic ip-address to a static name is a decent way to solve that problem.

Comment: ok.. so if i configure gps device  like this :   host:gpst.no-ip.com

      port:5555


  will it point to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555 on my server (assuming xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx be the ip of server at the time of call) ?

Comment: It will bind to `0.0.0.0` on your server (`INADDR_ANY`) which is all the interfaces (IP addresses) on your machine. However, I would suspect your server is really behind a consumer router, which means *its* IP doesn't change, your router's does ... unless you mean you have really cheap hosting or something, but if that's the case there has to be some mechanism in place or else it wouldn't be ... hosting.